# What should I call classwork at the start of a period?

Tags: american-english, synonyms, dialects

So as far as I can remember, whenever a teacher gives you work at the beginning of a class period, they are called "Drills" or "Warm-ups"; however, friends that I have talked to from other schools around the U.S. hear them called "Bell Ringers" or "Do Nows". Do certain parts of the U.S. call them differently then others? Or is it entirely dependent on the school?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.educationworld.com/a_curr/columnists/jones/jones020.shtml)

Comment: To me, "drills" are a particular kind of classwork, not necessarily performed at the beginning of a class period.  [Merriam-Webster agrees](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drill).  I don't recall having a specific term for what you describe when I was in school.

Comment: In New York, we call them Do Nows.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So it seems that there are different terms for different education boards around the U.S.

Comment: You should probably summarize them then.